# Null value coming for submitted value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**About**

This is about Spring Boot 2 Framework with Thymeleaf template engine

**Issue Details**

When trying to sumit the radio button values from input page, the output page shows null submitted value.

**Enumeration**

```
public enum GameOptions {
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

**Model**

```
public class UserData {
    private GameOptions _gameOption;

    public GameOptions get_gameOption() {
        return _gameOption;
    }

    public void set_gameOptions(GameOptions _gameOption) {
        this._gameOption = _gameOption;
    }
    
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class myController {
    
    @GetMapping({"/input"})
    public String inputPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("UserData", new UserData());
        return "input";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/output")
    public String outputPage(UserData UserData, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("UserData", UserData);
        return "output";
    }
}
```

**Template - Input Page**

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/output}" th:object="${UserData}">
    <div th:each="model : ${T(com.example.demo.GameOptions).values()}">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" th:field="${UserData._gameOption}" th:value="${model}">
            <label th:for="${model}" th:text="${model}">model</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Template - Output Page**

```
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${UserData._gameOption}" />
```

> Output Page shows id: null

Comment: try `<input type="radio" th:field="*{_gameOption}" th:value="${model}" >`

Comment: Still same value is null.

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The problems you have are due to your getters and setter on UserData.

This will work

```
class UserData {
    private GameOptions gameOption;

    public GameOptions getGameOption() {
        return gameOption;
    }

    public void setGameOption(GameOptions gameOption) {
        this.gameOption = gameOption;
    }
}
```

input.html

```
    ...
      <input type="radio" th:field="*{gameOption}" th:value="${model}">
    ...
```

output.html

```
  <p th:text="'id:' + ${UserData.gameOption}" />
```